# Are liquidity pools the decentralized exchange equivalent of storing assets on centralized exchanges?

Tags: exchanges, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, defi

We'd think that decentralized exchanges are just the same as centralized exchanges in terms of functional purposes which are

1. trading
2. storing crypto assets

However, the second item is not readily apparent on decentralized exchanges. Uniswap, for example, doesn't act as custodian of your crypto to just hold it there on the Uniswap exchange. Or does it?

All I could think is that the *decentralized equivalent* of storing assets on centralized exchanges are the liquidity pools made by decentralized exchange participants. Is this the correct analogy to explain how the second item is represented in DeFi?

If so, how to properly cement the analogy, given that liquidity pools are in many ways a cloud representation of many participants' holdings floating in thin air, in many ways very abstract and loosely defined. The concept still doesn't square up with the metaphysical act of storing holdings as would be done on centralized exchanges

Comment: bad analogy. Token contracts can have bugs, and liquidity pools can be drained by hackers, there are lots of examples of this you can find in google. Custody by some authority would be better for big investment firms

Comment: if liquidity pools (of legitimate tokens) can be drained by hackers, why all the hype about DeFi? Are we actually much safer using centralized exchanges rather than casting ourselves out to our own devices? My question is, if not liquidity pools, *what is* the decentralized equivalent?

Comment: on the blockchain all is safe as the expertise of the developers who created the contract. A complex contract poorly designed will have bugs, if not now, a year (or two) later for sure. Using poorly developed contract is as unsafe as poorly configured centralized exchenge. Centralized exchange also suffers from the same: human bugs. You can have an unhackable centralized exchange if you follow established security procedures  and automatize everything

Comment: is it true that there is no storing of crypto assets (on an exchange) when it comes to DEX? That, instead of trading on an exchange, which requires moving crypto from my possession into the temporary custody of a centralized exchange just to trade, with DEX, we are instead directly trading from our *own* possession/custody? Thus the rebranded verb "swapping"?

Comment: lots of hackers are around there, and they are spending lots of time on decompiling contracts and checking if you have known bugs in them.

Comment: how do hackers even locate  deployed smart contracts to exploit that were agreed on in private? Is there some sort of publicly disclosed index for the Ethereum blockchain that lists newly deployed smart contracts as they appear?

Comment: there is no privacy on the blockchain, and there couldn't be any, unless you encrypt all the data. In fact, the reason blockchain was adopted is due to all data is public and available for anyone. All the transactions your contract does are public, and also the storage of the contract can be read and analyzed even if variables inside the contract are declared as `private`

Comment: Which website lists newly deployed smart contracts by the minute?

Comment: I don't know of a website that does precisely that, you might check Etherscan API , but the official `geth` client will have all the transactions, you simply get all transactions of a block, and check the `To` address, if it is `nil`, then a new contract was deployed. To get the code of the contract you call `getCode()` function. And to read all the storage of the contract you need to use `trie` package of `go-ethereum` , you can iterate through contract storage with iterator functions and check its content, the are posts in Medium on how to do this, just google "merkle trie ethereum"

Answer (score 0):

No, decentralized exchanges aren't custodial. You have total control over your assets as only you can withdraw them (or permit someone else to do it if the contract enables that).

Comment: total control of our assets, but where are we putting them exactly when participating in DeFi? I don't see a `Funding` button on decentralized exchanges. Just buttons to engage in trading, which they just rebrand as "swapping". If we don't even deposit them in to the DEX, how can we even withdraw them?